# Find users with a specific property?

Tags: firebase

```
users
|
|_ john_doe199
|  |
|  |_ subscriptions
|    |
|    |__ service_id1 : true
|
|_ jane_doe123
   |
   |_ subscriptions
     |
     |__ service_id1 : true
     |__ service_id2 : true
```

Given this schema, how do I find users who are subscribed to `service_id1`?

Comment: Use a deep query: [Firebase Deep Query](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html). Its pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Jay Post this as an answer with a code snippet and I will accept :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to Eirik's answer

```
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("subscriptions/service_id1").queryEqualToValue(true)
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)
})
```

And this is called a [Firebase Deep Query](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<your_app>.firebaseio.com/users")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("subscriptions/service_id1")
   .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let subscribed = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("subscriptions/service_id1")
                        .value as? Bool {
        print("\(snapshot.key) is subscribed to service_id1: \(subscribed)")
    }
})
```